# Simplifying $\arctan \left(\frac{2x}{3}+\frac{2}{3}\right)$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

How can I simplify $\arctan \left(\frac{2x}{3}\right)$ in the form of $\arctan \left(x\right)$ ?

For example we can simplify $\arctan \left(-x\right)$ as $-\arctan \left(x\right)$
or $\arccos \left(-x\right)$ as $\pi -\arccos \left(x\right)$

Actually I got stuck integrating $\arctan \left(\frac{2x}{3}+\frac{2}{3}\right)$.

I am aware of the formula ***arctan α + arctan β = arctan (α+β) / (1-αβ)***

But I still need to simplify $\arctan \left(\frac{2x}{3}\right)$. So how can I do it? Explaining how to solve this integration may also help.

Thanks

Comment: you may want to let $u=\frac{2x}{3}+\frac{2}{3}$

Comment: please explain the use of doing so @cr001

Comment: you can rewrite it in the form $$\frac{1}{2} i \log \left(1-\frac{2}{3} i (x+1)\right)-\frac{1}{2} i \log
   \left(1+\frac{2}{3} i (x+1)\right)$$

Comment: See my answer @Shubham

Answer (score 1):

Let $u=\frac{2x}{3}+\frac{2}{3}$, then $du={2\over3}dx$

$\int{\arctan(\frac{2x}{3}+\frac{2}{3})}dx=\int{\arctan(u)}{3\over2}du={3\over2}(u\cdot\arctan(u)-{1\over2}ln(1+u^2))+C$